# Access contract type in SchemaFilterContext from Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen v6

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Consider the following implementation of `ISchemaFilter` under `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen v4.0.1.0`:

```
    public class RequireNonNullableValueTypePropertiesSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (schema.Type == "object" && context.JsonContract is JsonObjectContract jsonObjectContract)
            {
                var valueTypeProperties = jsonObjectContract.Properties
                                                            .Where(property => property.PropertyType.IsValueType)
                                                            .Where(property => !property.PropertyType.IsGenericType || property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Nullable<>))
                                                            .Select(property => property.PropertyName)
                                                            .ToList();
                if (valueTypeProperties.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (schema.Required == null)
                    {
                        schema.Required = new List<string>();
                    }
                    foreach (var valueTypeProperty in valueTypeProperties.Except(schema.Required))
                    {
                        schema.Required.Add(valueTypeProperty);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In v5 (release notes [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/releases/tag/v5.0.0-rc3)), `JsonContract` was removed from `SchemaFilterContext`, which breaks the `if` statement at:

`if (schema.Type == "object" && context.JsonContract is JsonObjectContract jsonObjectContract)`

I've been researching a refactoring solution for the past week or so, but I can't figure out how to check for the contract under the new version.

Does anybody know how I can retrieve the JsonContract under the new version?

I tried debugging the `Apply` method at runtime to understand the structure of the objects a little better, but given how the application was structured (detailed below), I could not get the breakpoint to hit in the dll.

Thanks in advance!

#### For context

- I have a set of class libraries that provide their own service contract definitions, called `ServiceContract1`, `ServiceContract2`, etc
- They leverage code from another class library, named `ServiceExtensions`
- All reside within the same solution
- The `ServiceContract` libraries are published as nuget packages, and are loaded by an external console application
- This console application provides the `Swagger` functionality by loading those nuget packages and making their Swagger definition available at the Swagger endpoint. It basically has a swagger generator that creates a swagger definition based on each package.